# Should put in requirements.txt dependency targeting package in pypi or github repo?

Tags: python, github, pypi

Are there any technical indications to prefer referencing a package on PyPI over the original source on GitHub in `requirements.txt`?

Only thing that comes to my mind is that freezing a package on a certain version is very cumbersome with GitHub (`package==1.0.0` vs `git://github.com/{ username }/{ reponame }.git@{ tag name }#egg={ desired egg name }`), but I'm not sure if this can cause any problems.

Other thing is necessity to install git on target machine.

Are there any other indications?

Comment: If you are installing from a release tag, then either is just a distribution mechanism, and it doesn't matter. If you are installing from an arbitrary revision, then GitHub has that revision, PyPI probably won't.

Comment: Mostly github has latest and development version if you want stable version you have to change branch or tag but when it comes to pypi or pip it will be stable versions only. and easy_install install newer version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPI is the accepted defacto location for distributing *released versions* of a package, and it could be that not all Python packaging tools support installing from GitHub.

And as you already noticed, for `pip` to support GitHub you must have `git` installed; this limits portability of your file.

Next, not all project maintainers remember to tag releases in GitHub; what is distributed to PyPI may be hard to locate on GitHub. The tag could also be *wrong*. You could end up installing a subtly different version from PyPI, creating confusion when you run into a support issue.

On the other hand, if you must install a non-released development version (say, you need a critical bugfix but no release has been rolled since), then GitHub may be the only place you can get that version.

So, in short, you should prefer using PyPI over GitHub, as that ensures that you got an official release, and is more portable. Only use a GitHub URL in `requirements.txt` if there is no other source for a specific version.